SSL Wrong Version Error when connecting to Azure IoT hub
I am using Python version 3.12.2 and azure-iot-device = 2.13.0 to receive and send message to the IoT Hub. The script works however I always run into the following error eventually. Looks like a connection problem. However, I don't understand why it appears some time in between. Any hints for this problem? Thanks! :)
enter image description here
I tried already to set the urllib3 version to 1.26.5. And checked my proxy settings are correct. But it did not solve the problem. Ideally the code should rung through a 4-hours loop without any problem.


SSL Wrong Version Error when connecting to Azure IoT hub

The above error occurs mostly when the version used in Python doesn't supports the version used by azure-iot-device. Check whether the version of Python supports azure-iot-device version or not and upgrade to the new version if not. Try with the versions used in the below code. The below code uses Python version 3.11.9

And the version of azure-iot-device is 2.13.0

It connected successfully to the azure-iot-device as shown the below output.
import logging
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient, Message, exceptions

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# IoT Hub connection string
CONNECTION_STRING = "<Connection_String>"

def send_message(client, message):
    try:
        msg = Message(message)
        client.send_message(msg)
        print("Message successfully sent")
    except exceptions.AzureError as e:
        print(f"Failed to send message due to AzureError: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred while sending the message: {e}")

def receive_message(client):
    try:
        print("Waiting for messages...")
        while True:
            message = client.receive_message()
            print(f"Message received: {message.data}")
    except exceptions.AzureError as e:
        print(f"Failed to receive message due to AzureError: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred while receiving the message: {e}")

def main():
    try:
        client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
        
        client.connect()
        print("Client connected")

        send_message(client, "Hello, IoT Hub!")

        receive_message(client)
        
    except exceptions.AzureError as e:
        print(f"Failed to connect or perform IoT operations due to AzureError: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        try:
            client.disconnect()
            print("Client disconnected")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to disconnect the client: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Message sent from Azure IOT Hub:

Output:


Could you try with the above code and let me know if you are facing with any errors.
